# form action with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that must execute a javascript function on submit, the function then posts data to my php send mail file and the mail is sent. But it only works in fire fox. The form action does not seem to be doing anything in IE, my question is: Is this the correct way to call a function from an external file from the form action:

```
action="javascript:simpleCart.checkout()"
```

simpleCart is the .js file and checkout() is the function.

Tips appreciated, struggling to understand why it would work in firefox but not IE, chrome or safari.

```
<form name=form onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:simpleCart.checkout()" method="post">
```

Comment: can't you call that function from validateFormOnSubmit?

Comment: no because simpleCart is the huge js file for my shopping cart and validateFormOnSubmit is from my validation .js file and i cant combine the files.

Comment: i see what your saying. Is it not correct to use action the way I have?

Comment: im already using jquery, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A form action set to a JavaScript function is not widely supported, I'm surprised it works in FireFox.

The best is to just set form `action` to your PHP script; if you need to do anything before submission you can just add to `onsubmit`

**Edit** turned out you didn't need any extra function, just a small change here:

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
    var reason = "";
    reason += validateName(theForm.name);
    reason += validatePhone(theForm.phone);
    reason += validateEmail(theForm.emaile);

    if (reason != "") {
        alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
    } else {
        simpleCart.checkout();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your form:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this);">
```

Comment: the trouble is that i need to run my validation, then run the checkout function which executes the php script

Comment: i put the function in the head like this `<script type=text/javascript>

function validateAndSubmit(form)
{
    if (validateFormOnSubmit(form)) {
        simpleCart.checkout();
    }
    return false;
}
</script>` and no luck

Comment: And you updated your form too? If so, any errors? Step through with debugger, etc.

Comment: it passes the values but doesnt run checkout

Comment: this is my submit button `<input type=submit name=Submit value=Send style=cursor:pointer />`

Comment: actually its not validating either

Comment: ok validation IS working but nothing happens when i click on submit

Comment: this function is working in that it validates the form and also sends the mail in firefox, chrome and safari but it still doesnt work in IE, any ideas why??

Comment: Hmm I will check it out and let you know

Comment: thanks, i can give you as much info as you need, im running out of ideas!

Comment: i have also found that you need to have an item in the cart for it to send

Comment: I've made a change to my answer, turns out there's some double functionality there that we could do without. Tested the form with IE9 and there's no problem that I can see.

Comment: With html5 you can omit the action property and if using jQuery you can use something like this:
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('form[name=form]').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
your validation logic
});

Answer (score 59):

### Absolutely valid.

```html
    <form action="javascript:alert('Hello there, I am being submitted');">
        <button type="submit">
            Let's do it
        </button>
    </form>
    <!-- Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and Safari -->
```

So for a short answer: ***yes***, this is an option, and a nice one. It says *"when submitted, please don't go anywhere, just run this script"* - quite to the point.

### But...!

Why don't we take this to the next level - let the event handler know which form we're dealing with! Here's how to do it. (Note how the first form, no matter how obvious, won't do the job. We need a few keystrokes more.)

```html
    <form action="javascript: myFunction( this ) ">  
    <!-- But this won't work -->

    <form action="javascript:;" onsubmit=" myFunction( this ) ">  
    <!-- Tadaammm! -->
```

Now you can access the sender form properly. (You can write a simple "#" as action, it's quite common - but it has a side effect of scrolling to the top when submitting.)

Again, I like this approach because it's effortless and self-explaining. No "return false", no jQuery/domReady, no heavy weapons. It just does what it seems to do. Surely other methods work too, but for me, this is The Way Of The Samurai.

#### A note on validation

Forms only get submitted if their `onsubmit` event handler returns something truthy, so you can easily run some preemptive checks:

```html
    <form action="/something.php" onsubmit=" return isMyFormValid ( this ) ">
```

Now *isMyFormValid* will run first, and if it returns false, server won't even be bothered. Needless to say, you will have to validate on server side too, and that's the more important one. But for quick and convenient early detection this is fine.

Comment: Ye olde "print this page" void(0) might be the safest, cross-platform way of doing this that will allow "Go" instead of "Return" keyboard button display as long as there is an element with type="submit" within the form.
<form name="login" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="myFunction(this)">

This is my solution for AngularJS apps:
<form name="login" action="javascript:void(0);" ng-submit="ctrl.login()">

Comment: It is weird (like many other things in js) that "javascript:" creates a separate scope. What is "this" then? Anyway, elegant and practical solution. Grats

Comment: @alvaroc It's the Window object I believe. Completely pointless.

Comment: Tried in Chrome, yes it's Window, article updated accordingly.

Comment: (Wonder why the "not widely supported" is still the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 5):

It has been almost 8 years since the question was asked, but I will venture an answer not previously given.  The OP said this doesn't work:

```
action="javascript:simpleCart.checkout()"
```

And the OP said that this code continued to fail despite trying all the good advice he got.  So I will venture a guess.  The action is calling `checkout()` as a static method of the `simpleCart` class; but maybe `checkout()` is actually an **instance** member, and not **static**.  It depends how he defined `checkout()`.

By the way, `simpleCart` is presumably a class name, and by convention class names have an initial capital letter, so let's use that convention, here.  Let's use the name `SimpleCart`.

Here is some sample code that illustrates defining `checkout()` as an instance member.  This was the correct way to do it, prior to  ECMA-6:

```
function SimpleCart() {
    ...
}
SimpleCart.prototype.checkout = function() { ... };
```

Many people have used a different technique, as illustrated in the following.  This was popular, and it worked, but I advocate against it, because instances are supposed to be defined on the `prototype`, just once, while the following technique defines the member on `this` and does so repeatedly, with every instantiation.

```
function SimpleCart() {
    ...
    this.checkout = function() { ... };
}
```

And here is an **instance** definition in ECMA-6, using an official `class`:

```
class SimpleCart {
    constructor() { ... }
    ...
    checkout()    { ... }
}
```

Compare to a **static** definition in ECMA-6.  The difference is just one word:

```
class SimpleCart {
    constructor() { ... }
    ...
    static checkout()    { ... }
}
```

And here is a static definition the old way, pre-ECMA-6.  Note that the `checkout()` method is defined outside of the function. It is a member of the *function* object, *not the prototype* object, and that's what makes it **static**.

```
function SimpleCart() {
    ...
}
SimpleCart.checkout = function() { ... };
```

Because of the way it is defined, a static function will have a different concept of what the keyword `this` references.  Note that **instance** member functions are called using the `this` keyword:

```
this.checkout();
```

**Static** member functions are called using the class name:

```
SimpleCart.checkout();
```

The problem is that the OP wants to put the call into HTML, where it will be in **global** scope.  He can't use the keyword `this` because `this` would refer to the global scope (which is `window`).

```
action="javascript:this.checkout()" // not as intended
action="javascript:window.checkout()" // same thing
```

There is no easy way to use an instance member function in HTML.  You can do stuff in combination with JavaScript, creating a registry in the static scope of the Class, and then calling a surrogate static method, while passing an argument to that surrogate that gives the index into the registry of your instance, and then having the surrogate call the actual instance member function.  Something like this:

```
// In Javascript:
SimpleCart.registry[1234] = new SimpleCart();

// In HTML
action="javascript:SimpleCart.checkout(1234);"

// In Javascript
SimpleCart.checkout = function(myIndex) {
    var myThis = SimpleCart.registry[myIndex];
    myThis.checkout();
}
```

You could also store the index as an attribute on the element.

But usually it is easier to just do nothing in HTML and do everything in JavaScript with `.addEventListener()` and use the `.bind()` capability.

Answer (score 1):

I always include the js files in the head of the html document and them in the action just call the javascript function. Something like this:

```
action="javascript:checkout()"
```

You try this?

Don't forget include the script reference in the html head.

I don't know cause of  that works in firefox.
Regards.

Comment: THe only way I can get thiis to work is using form action but it does not work in IE, i cant understand wjy the posted solutions are not working but they wont call simpleCart.chekout

Comment: The best way to do this in my opinion is jquery. Check this: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ submit event. And this ajax form http://www.queness.com/post/160/create-a-ajax-based-form-submission-with-jquery in this web there a demo.

Answer (score 0):

With nextJS server actions (experimental), one thing about submitting a form is that it sends formData with it. If you need to get formData, here is a solution i found from [MDN][1]. However, I haven't found a way to tell the experimental `useFormState` hook that the form is pending, so it will do the same as submitting, but does not update the pending state that the hook provides.

```
export default MyComponent(){
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(submitFormAction, initialState)

  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault()
      handleSubmitForm()
    }
  }

  const handleSubmitForm = async () => {
    const formElement: HTMLFormElement | null = document.querySelector("form");
    const formData = new FormData(formElement || undefined);
    await formAction(formData)
  }

  return(
    <form action={formAction}
      ...
    </form>
  )

}
```

EDIT:
After looking around, I found that I can get pending to function properly if I simply trigger the form button on enter, which ends up being a little simpler.

```
  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault()
      triggerSubmitClick()
    }
  }

  const triggerSubmitClick = () => {
    const submitButton: HTMLButtonElement | null = document.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
    if (submitButton) {
      submitButton.click();
    }
  }
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects