# Get value from $_POST PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need a help if possible,

I have the following code, and I need to get the user in login.php with $ User = $ _ POST ['User'];

However I can't ,someone please help me?

I can get the hash but not the User.

thank you so much

```
function login() {  
        var p = hex_sha1(document.getElementById('pass').value);  
        var k = document.getElementById('key').value;  
        var h = hex_sha1(k+p);  
        var hash = document.getElementById('hash');  
        hash.value = h;  
        var User = document.getElementById('User').value;         
        var f = document.getElementById('finalform');  
        f.submit();   
} 



<form action="javascript:login()" method="post" >   
    <input type="hidden" id="key" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" /> 
     <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="User" type="text" id="User" name="User" required>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" type="password" id="pass" required>
    </div>   
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
</form>

<form action="login.php" method="post" id="finalform">  
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" id="hash"/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="User" id="User"/> 
</form>
```

in login.php

```
$hash = $_POST['hash'];

$User = $_POST['User'];

echo $hash;

echo $User;
```

$User is null value, why?

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you alert values in your JS login() function?

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document, so go fix that first. And you are never setting a value for the hidden User field in the form that you are submitting, so ... what do you expect?

Comment: Use class instead of id

Comment: From the code you provided there is nothing showing that the `user` field gets any value at all.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520899/form-action-with-javascript

Comment: Why are you even using javascript here, you're not even using AJAX? Submit the form the regular php way. `<form action="login.php" method="post">` [Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `id="User"`, one in your visible form, one in your hidden form.

Also, unless you have a specific reason to do it as you're doing now, just use a normal form and let PHP do the hashing. If you're worried about security, add a SSL cerificate (price is not an excuse, as [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is free). Forms should be SSL-ed anyway.

Comment: Take his advice "don't do it this way". Since you're not using AJAX this is pointless. Front-end should not do the back-ends job.

Comment: Hello mihailo. Thanks for your comment. But is for a test, isnt for use :)

Comment: On this site, if you got an answer that fixed your problem, please mark it as answer, This helps other people recognize the answer (and in this case give me some points haha)

Answer (score 0):

Please use ajax call and directally call
base_url under the PHP:

```
url:'<?php echo base_url("Your Routes"); ?>'
```

like this
after that provide routes on routes file and call the function on your controller