# Hitting Enter to Submit Password Form, Works if Incorrect, Fails if Correct

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This password form behaves as expected when the password is incorrect, but when the password is correct then hitting ENTER on the KEYBOARD doesn't submit the form.

Here's the JavaScript:

```js
function TheLogin() {
  var password = 'beyond';
  if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
    top.location.href = "streettherapy224984.html";
  } else {
    window.alert("INCORRECT PASSWORD. ACCESS DENIED.");
  }
}

function forceLower(strInput) {
  strInput.value = strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<form name="login" style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <input class="main" type="text" name="pass" size="64" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) document.getElementById('codebtn').click()" style="width: 230px;" onkeyup="return forceLower(this);"><br>
  <div id="spacer20"></div>
  <input class="main" type="button" id="codebtn" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
```

I'm totally lost so any help figuring this out would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `this.document` drop the `this`. Forcing the string to lowercase as the user types is not going to be a fun experience. type a few characters and put cursor in the middle of it and type.

Comment: do you see anything in the console? (f12 if on a windows machine)

Comment: I edited your question to make it a snipplet and seems to work fine so..... what is different?

Comment: the snippet is working correctly!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this folks! I can't work it out... Here is the actual implementation; http://www.tanatu.com/entrycode854779.html

Comment: @Ben everything works fine in Chrome. what browser do you use?

Comment: is this marketing?

Comment: @Serge I'm on Chrome too - The page appears to refresh when hitting enter with the correct password. Also seeing a similar issue when on Safari on iOS.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious enough, this issue is to do with PRESSING THE ENTER KEY ON THE KEYBOARD

Comment: Update: I have solved this problem by having the Javascript click a hidden html link that opens in a new window.

Comment: please see my answer, you put a lot of unuseful code, like for the keypress 13... there is no need to do it for the Enter

Comment: updated, using windows.location.href

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here:

fix as is

```
1. <form ... onsubmit="TheLogin()">
2. <input ... type="submit" id="codebtn"...>
```

remove any keypress on the "pass" input, type "submit" will trigger "onsubmit" function, so theLogin

```js
function TheLogin() {
  var password = 'beyond';
  if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.tanatu.com/streettherapy224984.html";
  } else {
    alert("INCORRECT PASSWORD. ACCESS DENIED.");
  }
}

function forceLower(strInput) {
  strInput.value = strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

```css
form {margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;}
#pass {width: 230px;}
```

```html
<form name="login" onsubmit="TheLogin()">
  <input class="main" type="text" id="pass" onkeyup="return forceLower(this);">
  <hr>
  <input class="main" type="submit" id="codebtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

also

> If you want to simulate clicking on a link, use `location.href = URL`
>
> If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace(URL)`

Answer (score -1):

well, first. the method dont set and also the action. try this

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="javascript:TheLogin(this.form)" style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;">
<input class="main" type="text" name="pass" size="64" style="width: 230px;" ><br>
<div id="spacer20"></div>
<input class="main" type="button" id="codebtn" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
```

because they all in form, we dont need set the keyboard interaction trigger. all interaction is handled by form,even you press enter, it will send without onkeydown. except for input type button,so for button, we keep function thelogin for onClick to make it submit. in javascript we can set preventDefault for handle the form for make it dont auto submit.

thats a short explain. hope u understand.

Comment: I don't believe the OP is attempting to POST data; not sure how this would help.

Comment: sorry, the code got cut when i post it, now it has updated and tested in my localhost

Comment: Still not sure what you're attempting to do here, as this behavior of linking a Javascript function as a form action is [not widely supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520979/269970).

Comment: hmm, well, sorry then, im newbie here. maybe i got misunderstanding from his explain.im just think he want submit the pass he made for validation but dont submit it right and it also dont make it redirect to the url when press enter at the input.