# HTML/JS Script to validate login form fails on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a html/js script to validate a simple login page and on successful login, to redirect to the homepage. What I have so far is not doing the intended when I hit the submit button. Can someone please help? It is  much appreciated. My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- This is is the main start page saved in index.html -->
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h2>Login details</h2>

<form name="login" action="return validateForm()" action="http://localhost:8080/index.html" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
        function validateForm() {
        var un = document.login.username.value;
        var pw = document.login.password.value;
        var username = "username"
        var password = "password"
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
                return true;
        }
        else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [form action with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520899/form-action-with-javascript)

Comment: Form `action` is intended for the endpoint to call the form `method` on after the `submit` event. You're looking for `onsubmit` instead of `action`.

Comment: Thanks both DOn't Panic and Ahmed. It works!

Answer (score 0):

With the input from Don't Panic and Ahmed I have corrected the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- This is is the main start page saved in index.html -->
<html lang="en-US">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h2>Login details</h2>

<form name="login" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit()" action="http://localhost:8080/index.html" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
        function validateFormOnSubmit() {
        var un = document.login.username.value;
        var pw = document.login.password.value;
        var username = "username"
        var password = "password"
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
                return true;
        }
        else {
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
        }
}
</script>
```