# HTML pages render fine when opened with firefox, but show an error when ran in live server?

Tags: html, server

I have my index.html file and another file titled page2mainfeed.html, when you click the submit button in the the index file it takes you to the page2mainfeed.html. this works fine when the files are opened with Firefox, but when i try running them in live server, after i hit submit, i get the error message "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."  Here's the head for index.html,

```
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <title>Pigeon</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pigeonindex.css" />
   </head>
```

And here's the head for page2mainfeed.html

```
 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Pigeon</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page2mainfeed.css" />
 </head>
```

I'm pretty new to html so i'm sure the answers pretty simple, but none of the other solutions ive found have worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your form submitting to a server-side file? It likely has to do with the encoding of that file's output.

eg: a php file would need to include this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You might get some insight from some of the more recent answers in this post:

[The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996257/the-character-encoding-of-the-html-document-was-not-declared)

Comment: i don't have any php files, but i do have some javascipt files. Is there any way to declare javascript encoding?

Comment: Where is the form submitting, aka "action"? This is the file that needs to encode the output, eg:
    <form action="/action.php" method="get">
Or you can use some javascript on the same page as the form to handle the submit, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520899/form-action-with-javascript