# How to invoke a form action only when clicking the submit button

Tags: jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

When sending a jsf request without any query parameters to the page with the following jsf code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <head>
        <title>Search for Word</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="get" action="#{dictionary.search()}" id="search">
                <input jsf:id="keyword" value="#{dictionary.keyword}" />
            </form>
            <button type="submit" form="search" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the action `dictionary.search()` is always invoked even without clicking the submit button. However, the action is not expected to be invoked until the *submit* button is clicked.

Question: How to change the jsf code *without any other extra tag libraries but only the provided jsf tab lib, i.e. the pass-through element* so that the managed bean method `dictionary.method()` is invoked only when the *submit* button is clicked?

Comment: Check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520899/form-action-with-javascript

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and start with a beginners tutorial

Comment: @Tirth how will that help to invoke an action on a managed bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the answer myself:

```
            <form jsf:id="form">
                <input type="text" jsf:value="#{dictionary.keyword}" />
                <button jsf:action="#{dictionary.search}">Search</button>
            </form>
```

The nitty-gritty here is the *generation of the equivalent component tree of that generated by `h:commandButton`*

Based on the jsf 2.2 tutorial [8.5 HTML5-Friendly Markup](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm),

> To make an element that is not a JavaServer Faces element a pass-through element, specify at least one of its attributes using the http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf namespace

the whole form has to passed through to jsf as a *jsf component*, the `<form>` element has to be like this `<form jsf:id="form">`, where the value of the `id` actually could be at random

The same goes with both the `<input>` and `<button>` element and, as to the `<input>` element the `type` attribute has to be assigned with a value, here is `text`

Answer (score 1):

First - your submit button must be inside the form tag. And then try to set the action on the button, not on the form to avoid the submit.

Hope this helps.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h:form>
            ...
            <h:commandLink action="#{dictionary.search()}" value="Submit" />
        </h:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Up to @BalusC comment my best is:

```
<form method="get" id="search" jsf:action="#{bean.search}" >
    <input jsf:id="keyword" value="#{bean.keyword}" />
    <input type="submit" jsf:action="#{bean.search}" value="SUBMIT"
</form>
```

But only putting **jsf:action** on both tags, *form* and *input*, was possible make it work.

May be @BalusC can show us the correct way.

Comment: My question is: How to change the jsf code **without any other extra tag libraries but only the provided jsf tab lib, i.e. the pass-through element**. But in your answer, other tag library is used. Moreover, the namespace `p` does not make sense, or perhaps it is typo

Comment: Right, @Rui, I misunderstood the question about the tag libs. Here you have the response **without** other tag libs. I edited the response. Hope this time it really helps you. Cheers. BTW - **p** is for primefaces but it is external lib in this context.

Comment: thanks for your update, but just read it again, it is still not the answer of the question. The code I gave used jsf tag library only, meaning I did not intend to use h tag library. The answer could be "impossible" as well as long as you could reason it

Comment: You are absolutely right @Rui, I've just made some tests and the bean method is called every time you reload the page because of the plain html form tag. To avoid this you should use **xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"** and move the action to the submit button. So, the answer is: **impossible**.

Comment: It's not impossible: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#using-pass-through-elements OP's first mistake is that he used `action` on a wrong element instead of `jsf:action` on a proper element.

Comment: @BalusC If possible, could you give an answer with exact code? I am atm on Evgeni Enchev's side